# error: expected expression before ‘int’

Tags: c

This is for a project in a college class I'm taking that teaches in C. I am VERY new to C and programming in general and I struggle a lot with some of the errors sometimes.

I'm having an issue with the errors

```
level1.c:23: error: expected expression before ‘int’
```

and

```
level1.c:23: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

I've spent a long time trying different things to fix the error but I can't figure it out.
This is the source code that it comes from.

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int count;
    char *dictionary;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("need two arguments!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    count = readALLTokens(argv[1]);
    printf("there are %d tokens and strings\n",count);

    dictionary = memalloc(int *count);    /* ERROR ON THIS LINE */

    arrayfill(argv[1]);

    printf("THE DICIONARY...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n",dictionary[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the function it refers to in the other file with all of the other relevant functions.

```
int readALLTokens(char *);
int count = 0;

int readALLTokens(char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *token;

    fp = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"file %s could not be opened for reading\n",dictionary);
        exit(1);
    }
    token = readToken(fp);
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        printf("%s\n",token);
        ++count;
        free(token);
        token = readToken(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return count;
}

char *a[10];

int memalloc(int *count)
{
    *a = malloc(sizeof(count));
    return 0;
}

void arrayfill(char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(dictionary,"r");
    int t = 0;
    char *token;

    token = readToken(fp);
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s",*(a + t));
        ++t;
        free(token);
        token = readToken(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return;
}
```

The idea so far is that it is supposed to read the dictionary file, create an array and allocate an appropriate amount of memory for it then read the dictionary file into the array so that it can be used to compare to another file and "translate" it using the strings from the dictionary file.
I'm not sure how much of my code is correct but it seems to be able to do what I need it to up to this point.

Comment: Post your exact code - I guess maybe you left off some #include lines for brevity but those are important to this issue

Comment: can you describe (in english) what you expect "dictionary = memalloc(int *count);" to do; and also what "memalloc" is supposed to do?

Comment: I don't actually remember what "dictionary = memalloc(int *count);" is supposed to do. I wrote that a few days ago when I started the project. Now that I look at it I'm not entirely sure what I thought it was going to do in the first place. What I need to do at that point is allocate memory for the array "a[]" so that I can fill it with the tokens from dictionary in the arrayfill function. Also, I do have header file to reference all of these functions. I forgot to mention that earlier.

Comment: Also, I add #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdarg.h> to all of my .c files just as a blanket to hopefully cover all of the issues that not having those causes.

Answer (score 2):

**First things first:** Your code outputs a ton of warnings. Many of these relate to the fact that you don't have prototypes for your functions before you call them. You should **seriously** fix this.

**Secondly:** To pass a pointer to a variable, you use the `&` operator. As in:

```
dictionary = memalloc(&count);
```

Comment: The problem goes a lot deeper than that, the `memalloc` function doesn't need to change `count`, but it is completely broken